# Applications object browsing and manipulation at runtime

Tags: windows, object, testcomplete

I need to do an object browser/manipulator, similar to the one available in TestComplete, that is, list all the objects and their properties in any running foreign application, and being able to alter their properties, all of this during runtime, of course.
While MSAA/IAccessible can read objects, it can only return the visible objects, and not alter their properties as far as I know.
Using the WinAPI I couldn't read objects with no handles, in example, labels.

Ideally, I would like this done in Delphi, but any other language suggestions are acceptable.

Example of what I want to be able to do (This was done in TestComplete):

[image: TestComplete Object Browser]
[image: TestComplete Object Browser 2]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What would be an ideal way to list existing objects to read and alter their properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096071/what-would-be-an-ideal-way-to-list-existing-objects-to-read-and-alter-their-prop)

Answer (score 1):

The task is not an easy one. If you want to do this, you need to use specific approaches of getting the data for every application framework you want to work with (.NET, MFC, VCL, etc.). While some of these approaches are quite plain (e.g. Reflection for .NET and Java), some other can be more complex and not documented like in case of VCL. TestComplete loads its own hooks into the target process memory and retrieve information about this application via these modules.

Besides, as far as I know, TestComplete can read various types of debug information for tested applications and use it when exposing objects along with their members.

Using IAccessible and Win API is an easier way, though not so effective in some cases. You mentioned that you were unable to get any information from labels using Win API. This happens because TLabel objects in VCL applications are not window objects.